# Update password of a server without rebuilding/redeploying the WPF application

Tags: wpf, passwords

i am developing a WPF application with visual studio 2012.
This project involves a lot of connections to a database engine, 
in this case, i use SQL server 2012.
After i publishing my application for a while, i wish to change the password of the SQL server for security reason.
Is there any way that i can change the password without changing any code or redeploying my application?

Currently the connection string is stored in the app.config file.
any better way to do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should ask this question on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

theres a file named ProjectName.exe.config in your output folder it is the same as your app.config
just edit it...

Comment: hi Nahum, thank you for your answer. Yes i can edit the exe.config file, however, i also published the app as a setup.exe for others to use, the other users do not have this config file, do I have to re-publish a new setup.exe to the others? any efficient ways to do it? thanks again.